# Gentamicin drops safe for 4 week kitten?

Tags: cats, medicines

I have a 4 week old kitten that has one of it's eyes stuck shut. It Looks like the feline equivalent of pink eye.

I have some gentamicin sulfate eye drops from when one of my other cats had an abscess in the eyelid.

Is it safe for a kitten of only 4 weeks old to receive these drops?

I know I should see a vet to confirm this, but I won't be able to take it to a vet for a whole week.

Comment: Having been prescribed the stuff - its only supposed to be good for 30 days after opening. You don't really know if its still sterile

Comment: The vet told me when I received the drops that It wasn't necessary to refrigerate. Also the exp date on the side of the bottle is 08/19. They were opened 08/13/18. I am just worried about the chemical possibly affecting the developing eyes. Although this is probably an unfounded belief and I would imagine they'll be fine. Thanks for the input though, will go into my considerations.